# How do stackless coroutines differ from stackful coroutines?

Tags: c++, concurrency, coroutine, boost-coroutine

**Background:**

I'm asking this because I currently have an application with many (hundreds to thousands) of threads. Most of those threads are idle a great portion of the time, waiting on work items to be placed in a queue. When a work item comes available, it is then processed by calling some arbitrarily-complex existing code. On some operating system configurations, the application bumps up against kernel parameters governing the maximum number of user processes, so I'd like to experiment with means to reduce the number of worker threads.

**My proposed solution:**

It seems like a coroutine-based approach, where I replace each worker thread with a coroutine, would help to accomplish this. I can then have a work queue backed by a pool of actual (kernel) worker threads. When an item is placed in a particular coroutine's queue for processing, an entry would be placed into the thread pool's queue. It would then resume the corresponding coroutine, process its queued data, and then suspend it again, freeing up the worker thread to do other work.

**Implementation details:**

In thinking about how I would do this, I'm having trouble understanding the functional differences between stackless and stackful coroutines. I have some experience using stackful coroutines using the [Boost.Coroutine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/index.html) library. I find it's relatively easy to comprehend from a conceptual level: for each coroutine, it maintains a copy of the CPU context and stack, and when you switch to a coroutine, it switches to that saved context (just like a kernel-mode scheduler would).

What is less clear to me is how a stackless coroutine differs from this. In my application, the amount of overhead associated with the above-described queuing of work items is very important. Most implementations that I've seen, like [the new CO2 library](https://github.com/jamboree/co2) suggest that stackless coroutines provide much lower-overhead context switches.

Therefore, I'd like to understand the functional differences between stackless and stackful coroutines more clearly. Specifically, I think of these questions:

- [References like this one](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3708.pdf) suggest that the distinction lies in where you can yield/resume in a stackful vs. stackless coroutine. Is this the case? Is there a simple example of something that I can do in a stackful coroutine but not in a stackless one?
- Are there any limitations on the use of automatic storage variables (i.e. variables "on the stack")?
- Are there any limitations on what functions I can call from a stackless coroutine?
- If there is no saving of stack context for a stackless coroutine, where do automatic storage variables go when the coroutine is running?

Comment: 'Most of those threads are idle a great portion of the time, waiting on work items to be placed in a queue' - if this is the case, why are there so many threads?

Comment: @MartinJames: For legacy reasons. I'm not claiming that it's a good design as is, hence my desire to improve it. Refactoring the entire application wholesale isn't a near-term option, so I'm looking for relatively simple retrofits to begin with. Potentially complicating things further, the blocking call to the queue is typically made several levels deep in the call stack (i.e. not at the worker thread's top-level function). I *think* this would preclude the use of stackless threads in this specific context.

Comment: See also `boost::asio`.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

First, thank you for taking a look at [CO2](https://github.com/jamboree/co2) :)

The Boost.Coroutine [doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/coroutine/intro.html#coroutine.intro.stackfulness) describes the advantage of stackful coroutine well:

> **stackfulness**
>
> In contrast to a stackless coroutine *a stackful coroutine
>   can be suspended from within a nested stackframe*. Execution resumes at
>   exactly the same point in the code where it was suspended before. With
>   a stackless coroutine, only the top-level routine may be suspended.
>   Any routine called by that top-level routine may not itself suspend.
>   This prohibits providing suspend/resume operations in routines within
>   a general-purpose library.
>
> **first-class continuation**
>
> A first-class continuation can be passed as
>   an argument, returned by a function and stored in a data structure to
>   be used later. In some implementations (for instance C# yield) the
>   continuation can not be directly accessed or directly manipulated.
>
> Without stackfulness and first-class semantics, some useful execution
>   control flows cannot be supported (for instance cooperative
>   multitasking or checkpointing).

What does that mean to you? for example, imagine you have a function that takes a visitor:

```
template<class Visitor>
void f(Visitor& v);
```

You want to transform it to iterator, with stackful coroutine, you can:

```
asymmetric_coroutine<T>::pull_type pull_from([](asymmetric_coroutine<T>::push_type& yield)
{
    f(yield);
});
```

But with stackless coroutine, there's no way to do so:

```
generator<T> pull_from()
{
    // yield can only be used here, cannot pass to f
    f(???);
}
```

In general, stackful coroutine is more powerful than stackless coroutine.
So why do we want stackless coroutine? short answer: efficiency.

Stackful coroutine typically needs to allocate a certain amount of memory to accomodate its runtime-stack (must be large enough), and the context-switch is more expensive compared to the stackless one, e.g. Boost.Coroutine takes 40 cycles while CO2 takes just 7 cycles in average on my machine, because the only thing that a stackless coroutine needs to restore is the program counter.

That said, with language support, probably stackful coroutine can also take the advantage of the compiler-computed max-size for the stack as long as there's no recursion in the coroutine, so the memory usage can also be improved.

Speaking of stackless coroutine, bear in mind that it doesn't mean that there's no runtime-stack at all, it only means that it uses the same runtime-stack as the host side, so you can call recursive functions as well, just that all the recursions will happen on the host's runtime-stack. In contrast, with stackful coroutine, when you call recursive functions, the recursions will happen on the coroutine's own stack.

To answer the questions:

- Are there any limitations on the use of automatic storage variables
  (i.e. variables "on the stack")?

No. It's the emulation limitation of CO2. With language support, the automatic storage variables *visible to the coroutine* will be placed on the coroutine's internal storage. Note my emphasis on "visible to the coroutine", if the coroutine calls a function that uses automatic storage variables internally, then those variables will be placed on the runtime-stack. More specifically, stackless coroutine only has to preserve the variables/temporaries that can be used after resumed.

To be clear, you can use automatic storage variables in CO2's coroutine body as well:

```
auto f() CO2_RET(co2::task<>, ())
{
    int a = 1; // not ok
    CO2_AWAIT(co2::suspend_always{});
    {
        int b = 2; // ok
        doSomething(b);
    }
    CO2_AWAIT(co2::suspend_always{});
    int c = 3; // ok
    doSomething(c);
} CO2_END
```

As long as the definition does not precede any `await`.

- Are there any limitations on what functions I can call from a
  stackless coroutine?

No.

- If there is no saving of stack context for a stackless coroutine,
  where do automatic storage variables go when the coroutine is
  running?

Answered above, a stackless coroutine doesn't care about the automatic storage variables used in the called functions, they'll just be placed on the normal runtime-stack.

If you have any doubt, just check CO2's source code, it may help you understand the mechanics under the hood ;)

Answer (score 6):

What you want are user-land threads/fibers - usually you want to suspend the your code (running in fiber) in a deep nested call stack (for instance parsing messages from TCP-connection). In this case you can not use stackless context switching (application stack is shared between stackless coroutines -> stack frames of called subroutines would be overwritten).

You can use something like boost.fiber which implements user-land threads/fibers based on boost.context.

Comment: My main challenge with implementing this using fibers or coroutines is the issue of scheduling. I'd like to implement a M:N threading model, where the N fibers/coroutines are serviced by M kernel threads, but I would like those M threads to be able to service any of the N fibers/coroutines as needed. Is it possible to resume a `boost::fiber` from a different kernel thread than it was previously suspended from? Is there a performance hit for doing so? What about a `boost::asymmetric_coroutine`?

Comment: migrating a fiber from one thread to another is in development at the moment but I would not recommend it. moving one fiber makes only sense if the fiber is executed on another CPU. moving the fiber from one CPU to another would cause cache misses. boost.fiber provides synchronization classes like mutext/condition variables etc for fibers.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I do feel like it would be a useful feature. Like I said, in my application, I want to do M:N threading. I would have N fibers, each representing a processing pipeline. Those pipelines are all asynchronously fed with data from another thread. Therefore, I would like to be able to service each of the N fibers using M (much smaller than N) kernel threads. That means that whenever a particular fiber gets ready to run because new input data is available, I would like to take one of the kernel threads in the pool and service the fibers.

Comment: If I tie fibers specifically to threads, that could lead to reduced concurrency if a fiber's thread is busy at the time that it becomes ready (but another thread in the pool is available to run it). I don't know that I would need inter-fiber synchronization at all, so perhaps Boost.Coroutine itself may be an option (which I understand does support the migration of coroutines across threads).

Comment: FWIW, here's a CO2/ASIO example: https://github.com/jamboree/co2/blob/master/example/asio_threadpool.cpp