# What does it mean for "With a stackless coroutine, only the top-level routine may be suspended."

Tags: c++, coroutine, c++20, c++-coroutine

I found that statement from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28989543/7614469). At first I was astonished because I believe that makes stackless coroutines almost useless (And C++ coroutine TS is stackless). So I wrote a demo (In visual studio using C++ coroutine TS):

```
#include<experimental/coroutine>
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<mutex>
#include<future>
#include<chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std::experimental;

class AsyncQueue {
public:
    class Awaitable {
        friend AsyncQueue;
        AsyncQueue& mQueue;
        coroutine_handle<> mCoroutineHandle;
        Awaitable* mNext = nullptr;
    public:
        Awaitable(AsyncQueue& queue):mQueue(queue){}

        bool await_ready() const noexcept {
            return false;
        }

        bool await_suspend(coroutine_handle<> coroutineHandle) noexcept
        {
            mCoroutineHandle = coroutineHandle;
            mQueue.enqueue(this);
            return true;
        }

        void await_resume() noexcept {}
    };
private:
    mutex mMutex;
    Awaitable* mHead = nullptr;
    Awaitable* mTail = nullptr;
    void enqueue(Awaitable* awaitable){
        lock_guard<mutex> g{ mMutex };
        if (mTail) {
            mTail->mNext = awaitable;
            mTail = awaitable;
        }
        else {
            mTail = awaitable;
            mHead = mTail;
        }
    }

    Awaitable* dequeue() {
        lock_guard<mutex> g{ mMutex };
        Awaitable* result = mHead;
        mHead = nullptr;
        mTail = nullptr;
        return result;
    }

public:
    Awaitable operator co_await() noexcept {
        return Awaitable{ *this };
    }

    bool poll() {
        Awaitable* awaitables = dequeue();
        if (!awaitables) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            while (awaitables) {
                awaitables->mCoroutineHandle.resume();
                awaitables = awaitables->mNext;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
};


AsyncQueue toBackgroundThread;
AsyncQueue toMainThread;

std::future<void> secondLevel(int id)
{
    co_await toBackgroundThread;
    cout << id << " run on " << this_thread::get_id() << endl;
    co_await toMainThread;
    cout << id << " run on " << this_thread::get_id() << endl;
}

std::future<void> topLevel() {
    co_await secondLevel(1);
    co_await secondLevel(2);
}

void listen(AsyncQueue& queue) {
    while (true) {
        if (!queue.poll()) {
            this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    thread([]() {
        listen(toBackgroundThread);
    }).detach();

    topLevel();

    listen(toMainThread);
}
```

coroutine `topLevel` calls two `secondLevel` (which I believe are suspendable non-top-level routines), and it works fine.
The code above prints:

```
1 run on 16648
1 run on 3448
2 run on 16648
2 run on 3448
```

From that answer it is claimed that `This prohibits providing suspend/resume operations in routines within a general-purpose library.` I see no prohibitions here.

Comment: I have trouble understanding this code snippet. Where is the place when the bottom stackless coroutine is getting suspended here? Can't this example be shortened, by removing threads and queues (that seem completely irrelevant to the subject)?

Comment: @VTT This is the shortest I can reach because I don't have any ready made coroutines to use. You can ignore the thread and queue. just focus on function `topLevel` and `secondLevel`. The code after `co_await toBackgroundThread;` runs on background thread and the code after `co_await toMainThread;` runs on main thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each invocation of `co_await`, only the top level coroutine is suspended. To suspend a lower level, *that level* must suspend itself explicitly. And at that point, it is now the current "top level". So in every case, only the current top level gets suspended.

Compare this to a purely hypothetical stackful coroutine library:

```
//This function will always print the same thread ID.
void secondLevel(int id)
{
    while(!toBackgroundThread.poll())
      suspend_coroutine();

    cout << id << " run on " << this_thread::get_id() << endl;

    while(!toBackgroundThread.poll())
      suspend_coroutine();

    cout << id << " run on " << this_thread::get_id() << endl;
}

void topLevel() {
    secondLevel(1);
    secondLevel(2);
}

void listen(AsyncQueue& queue) {
    while (true) {
        if (!queue.poll()) {
            this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    thread([]() {
        listen(toBackgroundThread);
    }).detach();

    auto coro = create_coroutine(topLevel);
    coro.switch_to();

    toMainThread.ready(); //Notes that the main thread is waiting
    while (true) {
        if (!toMainThread.poll()) {
            coro.switch_to();
        }
    }
};
```

`topLevel` doesn't have any explicit suspension machinery. Yet its execution suspends whenever any function it calls suspends execution. The entire call-stack, defined by the function given to `create_coroutine` and everything it calls, suspends. That's how a stackful coroutine works.

That is what is being contrasted with when it comes to stackless coroutines. In the stackless version, every function that needs to suspend must be *specifically coded* to do so. And thus isn't really "general purpose" anymore; it's now special-cased to suspending scenarios.

Comment: But why having to suspend explicitly `prohibits providing suspend/resume operations in routines within a general-purpose library`?

Comment: @JohnSmith: Because the "general-purpose library" *doesn't know about `co_await`*. Consider an algorithm like `std::generate`. Is it going to invoke `co_await` on the return value of the functor before shoving it into the output iterator? No. Therefore, you cannot *make* `std::generate` suspend through the use of that functor. Whereas in the stackful version, you can.

Comment: Or to put it another way, you would end up with a version of `generate` that `co_await`s on the functor's values, and a version of `generate` that doesn't. These would be two different functions with different code, and you would have to pick which one to call them depending on whether you need one that can suspend or not. The `co_await` version is no longer "general-purpose", since it cannot handle non-suspending functors.

Comment: @NicolBolas Is there a reason why the `co_await` version cannot handle non-suspending functors?  I'm unaware of one (except maybe current syntax), and in generic code a non-suspending `co_await` could have 0 cost.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: Because `co_await` *requires* that the type of the expression provides the await machinery. `co_await 5;` and `co_await thing_that_returns_5();` is ill-formed.

Comment: @NicolBolas Sure, but that is syntax, not anything essential.  A rule stating "in generic code, `co_await thing_that_returns_5();` is `thing_that_returns_5();`" isn't unheard of; C++ did similar for functions returning void and the like.  Heck, `auto x = maybe_await( [&]{ return /* code */; })` should be writable without any change to the language, where `maybe_await` probes the return value of the lambda and if it is awaitable does a `co_await`, and otherise just invokes it.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: Well you can't do that because `co_await` doesn't live past the function it's in. `maybe_await` cannot cause the function that *calls it* to await. You have to do `if constexpr` gymnastics to make that work. Also, what happens if you want to generate a container of awaitable types, but you don't want to *await* on them? Say, you're generating a `vector<future<int>>`. Your hypothetical `generate` function would detect that the return type is an awaitable and therefore `co_await` on the value.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: The overall point is this: `co_await` is fundamentally *viral*. That is its nature. If you want to suspend thorough a function, that function has to be explicitly written to do that. This is the #1 argument against `co_await`-style coroutines.