# What is the difference between suspend-up and suspend-down coroutines?

Tags: c++, coroutine

The C++ community is currently discussing suspend-up vs suspend-down coroutines.

For example, suspend-down is mentioned in this proposal: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4453.pdf

What do these two terms mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terminology seems to be explained in [p0099r1: "A low-level API for stackful context switching"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0099r1.pdf) which says:

> Notes on suspend-up and suspend-down terminology The terms suspend-up
> and suspend-down were introduced in paper N4232 <sup>2</sup> and carried forward
> in P0158 <sup>9</sup> to distinguish stackless ( suspend-up ) and stackful (
> suspend-down ) context switching. These terms rely on a particular
> visualization of the C++ function call operation in which calling a
> function passes control “downwards,” whereas returning from a function
> passes control “upwards.” The authors recommend the terms
> suspend-by-return instead of suspend-up , and suspend-by-call instead
> of
> *suspend-down* . The recommended terminology directly references the
> underlying C++ operations, without requiring a particular
> visualization.
> *suspend-by-return* ( *suspend-up* , or “stackless” context
> switching) is based on returning control from a called function to its
> caller, along with some indication as to whether the called function
> has completed and is returning a result or is merely suspending and
> expects to be called again. The called function’s body is coded in
> such a way that – if it suspended – calling it again will direct
> control to the point from which it last returned. This describes both
> P0057 6 resumable functions and earlier technologies such as
> Boost.Asio coroutines. <sup>12</sup>
> *suspend-by-call* ( *suspend-down*, or
> “stackful” context switching) is based on calling a function which,
> transpar- ently to its caller, switches to some other logical chain of
> function activation records. (This may or may not be a contiguous
> stack area. The processor’s stack pointer register, if any, may or may
> not be involved.) This describes N4397 3 coroutines as well as
> Boost.Context, 13 Boost.Coroutine2 <sup>14</sup> and Boost.Fiber. <sup>15</sup>
> std::execution_context<>::operator()() requires suspend-by-call
> semantics.

Both are old papers and is separate from [p0057](http://wg21.link/p0057) which seems to be the main coroutines paper. p0444 discusses trying to unify these paper but does not seem to have gone anywhere. Also see [Trip Report: C++ Standards Meeting in Issaquah, November 2016](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2016/11/25/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-issaquah-november-2016/) which says:

> The Coroutines TS contains the co_await proposal, based on Microsoft’s original design.
>
> As mentioned previously, there are efforts underway to standardize a proposal for a different, stackful flavour of coroutines, as well as an exploratory effort to unify the two flavours under a common syntax. These proposals, however, are not currently slated to target the Coroutines TS. They may instead target a different TS (and if a unified syntax emerges, it could be that syntax, rather than the one in the Coroutines TS, that’s ultimately merged into the C++ standard).

Comment: Also relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977302/how-do-stackless-coroutines-differ-from-stackful-coroutines

Answer (score 0):

each function creates a stack frame (reserves space on the stack for local variables etc.)

suspend-up:

- used by stackless context switching (coroutines...)
- because you have only one stack (applications stack), you have to remove the stack frame of the suspended function (function of stackless coroutine)
- otherwise other functions, executed after the coroutine has been suspended, would write their own stack frame and thus corrupt the stack frame of the suspended one
- suspend-up == remove stack frame of suspended function == step some addresses at the stack upwards (for architectures where the stack grows from high to low addresses)

suspend-down:

- used by stackful context switching (coroutines, fibers, ...)
- each coroutine/fiber gets their own stack, thus the application consist out of multiple stacks
- if a stackful coroutine is suspended, the stack frame remains on the stack (because zhr stack is specific to/owned by the coroutine)
- the stack pointer is simply changed to another stack (== switching to another stackful coroutine/fiber)
- because the stack frame remains on the stack, it is called suspend-down