# What is the stack size of a boost coroutine?

Tags: c++, boost, stack-size, boost-coroutine, boost-coroutine2

What is the optimum stack size we need to have with boost::coroutine2? Do we need to match it with the thread stack size?
(https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/context/doc/html/context/stack.html)

Comment: From documentation *At construction a coroutine starts with a default (minimal) stack size. This minimal stack size is the maximum of page size*, and another sentence *it is not always possible to accurately estimate the required stack size*. If you don't know what amount of stack space you need, read about [segmented stacks](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/context/doc/html/context/stack/segmented.html), where stack size is increased as needed.

Comment: @rafix07 this sounds like an answer to me

Comment: I can not use segmented stacks due to performance reasons. I think it is always safe, if coroutine stack size is equal to thread stack size. Isn't it?