# Is it possible to use co_yield in a callback that is entered multiple times?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

I am learning C++20, and there are a question about coroutines. Suppose there is a function that uses a callback to iterate over the data:

```
void get_number( function<void(int)> callback )
{
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) callback(i);       
}
```

Is it possible to turn it into generator using `co_yield` in C++20 like below code?

```
generator<int> co_get_number()
{
    auto co_callback = [](int i){
       // is it possible use co_yield here?
       // co_yield i;
    }
    get_number(co_callback);
}
    
int main()
{
    for(int i : co_get_number())
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```

Thanks to chris, since the C++20 coroutine is stackless, it cannot be suspended within a nested stackframe.
However, I think this requirement is more practical, is there some neat way to make stackless coroutine also do that?

Comment: [Probably some good reading on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977302/how-do-stackless-coroutines-differ-from-stackful-coroutines). C++ coroutines are stackless.

Comment: I researched your link and in conclusion, the answer is no. Coroutines in C++20 are stackless and can only be used in top-level coroutines. Is that right? @chris

Comment: That is correct. Stackless coroutines can't suspend from within a function call because they don't save a separate stack for the parameters and other assorted data.